# Separar palabras en columnas nuevas marcadas por signos de puntuación

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

En el programa que estoy haciendo me pasan un fichero excel que contiene dos columnas, una con nombres y la otra con diferentes palabras. El problema que tengo es que en la columna de palabras hay campos donde solo hay una palabra, pero en otros hay muchas separadas por diferentes signos de puntuación.

La idea es que tengo que separar esos campos que tienen diferentes signos de puntuación en diferentes columnas y conservando el nombre que se le asocia.

Algunos datos que contiene el fichero son los siguientes:

```
nombre,palabras
Juan,e-learning; percepción; web
Carlos,IA / machine learning 
Sergio,escuela
Antonio,corredor,atleta
....
```

Lo que he intentado ha sido lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('fichero.csv', delimiter=',')
df.palabras = df.palabras.str.split(",;,/-*")
df = df.explode("palabras")
```

El problema que tengo con esto es que hay palabras como **e-learning** que no me interesa que se separen, ya que perdería su significado al hacerlo y no sé cómo hacer que este tipo de palabras no se separen.

El resultado que debería quedar es el siguiente:

```
nombre,palabra
Juan,e-learning
Juan,percepción
Juan,web
Carlos,IA
Carlos,machine learning
Sergio,escuela
Antonio,corredor
Antonio,atleta
....
```

¿Cómo podría solucionar ese problema?

Comment: Si no quieres que palabras compuestas con guión como `e-learning` se separen, deberías quitar el guión de la expresión regular usada en `.split()`. Naturalmente eso dejará "pegadas" todas las palabras en las que haya guiones. Si existen casos en los que esas palabras deban separarse, pero otros en los que deban estar pegadas, entonces el problema no está bien definido, ya que no aclaras cuáles son esos casos. Si son pocos casos los "excepcionales", podrías tener una lista de excepciones para manejarla de forma especial, pero sería necesario antes que aclares bien qué casos excepcionales tienes

Answer (score 0):

Te paso un ejemplo similar que hice yo hace unos días con un archivo .txt, podes adaptarlo a tu ejemplo.

```
f = open("olympics2.txt", "r")

lines = f.readlines()

header = lines[0]
print(header)
field_names = header.strip().split(",")
print(field_names)

for row in lines[1:]:
    vals = row.strip().split(",")
    if vals[5] != " NA":
        print("{}: {}; {}; {}; {}; {}".format(vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], vals[3], vals[4], vals[5]))

f.close()
```

El archivo que use, olympics2.txt, es el siguiente:

```
Name, Sex, Age, Team, Event, Medal
A Dijiang, M, 24, China, Basketball, NA
A Lamusi, M, 23, China, Judo, NA
Gunnar Nielsen Aaby, M, 24, Denmark, Football, NA
Edgar Lindenau Aabye, M, 34, Denmark/Sweden, Tug-Of-War, Gold
Christine Jacoba Aaftink, F, 21, Netherlands, Speed Skating, NA
Christine Jacoba Aaftink, F, 21, Netherlands, Speed Skating, NA
Christine Jacoba Aaftink, F, 25, Netherlands, Speed Skating, NA
Christine Jacoba Aaftink, F, 25, Netherlands, Speed Skating, NA
Christine Jacoba Aaftink, F, 27, Netherlands, Speed Skating, NA
Christine Jacoba Aaftink, F, 27, Netherlands, Speed Skating, NA
Per Knut Aaland, M, 31, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
Per Knut Aaland, M, 31, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
Per Knut Aaland, M, 31, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
Per Knut Aaland, M, 31, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
Per Knut Aaland, M, 33, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
Per Knut Aaland, M, 33, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
Per Knut Aaland, M, 33, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
Per Knut Aaland, M, 33, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
John Aalberg, M, 31, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
John Aalberg, M, 31, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
John Aalberg, M, 31, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
John Aalberg, M, 31, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
John Aalberg, M, 33, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
John Aalberg, M, 33, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
John Aalberg, M, 33, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
John Aalberg, M, 33, United States, Cross Country Skiing, NA
"Cornelia ""Cor"" Aalten (-Strannood)", F, 18, Netherlands, Athletics, NA
"Cornelia ""Cor"" Aalten (-Strannood)", F, 18, Netherlands, Athletics, NA
Antti Sami Aalto, M, 26, Finland, Ice Hockey, NA
"Einar Ferdinand ""Einari"" Aalto", M, 26, Finland, Swimming, NA
Jorma Ilmari Aalto, M, 22, Finland, Cross Country Skiing, NA
Jyri Tapani Aalto, M, 31, Finland, Badminton, NA
Minna Maarit Aalto, F, 30, Finland, Sailing, NA
Minna Maarit Aalto, F, 34, Finland, Sailing, NA
Pirjo Hannele Aalto(Mattila-), F, 32, Finland, Biathlon, NA
Arvo Ossian Aaltonen, M, 22, Finland, Swimming, NA
Arvo Ossian Aaltonen, M, 22, Finland, Swimming, NA
Arvo Ossian Aaltonen, M, 30, Finland, Swimming, Bronze
Arvo Ossian Aaltonen, M, 30, Finland, Swimming, Bronze
Arvo Ossian Aaltonen, M, 34, Finland, Swimming, NA
Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen, M, 28, Finland, Ice Hockey, Bronze
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 28, Finland, Gymnastics, Bronze
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 28, Finland, Gymnastics, Gold
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 28, Finland, Gymnastics, NA
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 28, Finland, Gymnastics, Gold
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 28, Finland, Gymnastics, NA
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 28, Finland, Gymnastics, NA
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 28, Finland, Gymnastics, NA
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 28, Finland, Gymnastics, Gold
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 32, Finland, Gymnastics, NA
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 32, Finland, Gymnastics, Bronze
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 32, Finland, Gymnastics, NA
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 32, Finland, Gymnastics, NA
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 32, Finland, Gymnastics, NA
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 32, Finland, Gymnastics, NA
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 32, Finland, Gymnastics, NA
Paavo Johannes Aaltonen, M, 32, Finland, Gymnastics, NA
Timo Antero Aaltonen, M, 31, Finland, Athletics, NA
Win Valdemar Aaltonen, M, 54, Finland, Art Competitions, NA
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.